# menu item on click Display none

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu like the following,

```
    <li class="dropdown whitedrop" id="dropdown" style="width: 229px;">
        <a data-target="#" class="fnd-nav-link hoverwithgreen" data-toggle="dropdown"><span id="loggedon_lable">Logged on:</span>
            <span id="loggedon_user"></span></a>
            <ul id="whitedropdown-menu" class="whitedropdown-menu">         
            <li class="borderli activemenu" id="psacheck2">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Process Management</a>
            </li>
            <li class="borderli disabledMenu" id="modulemgt">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">Module Management</a>
            </li>           
        </ul>
    </li>
```

I use the following css to make the menu appear on hover:

```
    .whitedropdown-menu{ 
        display: none;
    }

    .whitedrop:hover .whitedropdown-menu{
        display : block;
    }
```

But once i click on either "process management" menu item or "module management" menu item. I want the menu to disappear (disappear in the sense ".whitedropdown-menu" back to "display none").

How can i do that?

Please help,
Thanks.

Comment: css does not have capability to handle clicks. though you may use a hack where you use hidden `checkboxes` to toggle displays. but that requires additional tags. I suggest the use of javascript to accomplish what you want.

Comment: U have to use jquery or javascript for that

Comment: @jacelysh Actually, CSS has some limited capacity for handling clicks. For example, you could add `tabindex="0"` to `whitedropdown-menu` and add `.whitedrop:hover .whitedropdown-menu:active { display: none; }` and you'd have a working solution. The problem is that browsers are buggy with this non-standard approach, so it only really seems to work in Firefox and partially in Safari. However, there is no reason it shouldn't work in all browsers, so this should be filed as a bug in IE and Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Here's a more complete solution. Bind both the showing and hiding to event listeners. You can even replace `show()` with `slideDown()` and `hide()` with `slideUp()` if you want some animation.

CSS:

```
.whitedropdown-menu{ 
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('#dropdown').on('mouseover', function() {
    $('.whitedropdown-menu').show();
});

$('.whitedropdown-menu > li').on('click', function() {
    $('.whitedropdown-menu').hide();
});
```

END EDIT

---

You'll need JavaScript for this.

JS:

```
function hideMenu() {
  document.getElementById('whitedropdown-menu').style.display = 'none';
}
```

You can replace the `javascript:void(0)` in your HTML with `javascript:hideMenu()` to call this function, although there are better ways.

Comment: It works. But next time when i hover menu is not there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript onclick event to set display none attribute

Answer (score 0):

Use id instead of class in css

then follow the answer given by @flowstoneknight

Answer (score 0):

How about jquery?

`// hide() is equivalent to display:none;`

`$('#dropdown').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $('#whitedropdown-menu').hide();
});`

`// also you should have an event for the hover`
`$('#dropdown').mouseover(function() {
    $('#whitedropdown-menu').show();
});`